# Convert callback code into async code in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am new in javascript and nodejs. I want to convert callback function in async function. Can anybody help me with example?

for example:

```
exports.list = function(req, res){

  req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

        var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM customer',function(err,rows)
        {

            if(err)
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
            res.send(rows);

         });

         //console.log(query.sql);
    });

};
```

be the callback which is listing all the user in the database. I want to do this using functions of async module like `async.paralel()` , `async.series()`,etc....

Comment: please post a sample

Comment: You can't generically convert any function into an asynchronous function.  You can schedule it to run later, but if it's synchronous then you can't make it asynchronous.  We can only really help you if you post the code in question.  Questions about code SHOULD include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: sry for not including the code. I had edited my question. Can you please help? @jfriend00

Comment: FYI, promises is the modern way to handle and coordinate asynchronous operations, not the async library.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Bluebird http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

works like this

```
var fs = require("fs");
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);
// Now you can use fs as if it was designed to use bluebird promises from the beginning

fs.readFileAsync("file.js", "utf8").then(...)
```

Comment: can you suggest me without using promises?

Comment: what would you suggest instead of promises @vaibhavkaushik?

Comment: @vaibhavkaushik  you can use Observers, any reason you don't want to use promise.

Comment: @vaibhavkaushik Async functions use either promises or async/await (which are basically the same thing).

Comment: as i said I am new in javascript and node and haven't clear the concept of promises yet. @rajansoft1

Comment: So, what do **you** mean by `async function`? @vaibhavkaushik - are you referring to [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

I have been doing it a bit differently lately:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const { readFile } = require('fs');
const asyncReadFile = promisify(readFile);

asyncReadFile('foo.txt').then(data => {})

// or using async/await

async function doSomething () {
  const data = await asyncReadFile('foo.txt');
}
```

**Original answer:**

You can use `util.promisify` for that, it is native to Node.js since v8.0.0. The full documentation is available [here](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html), but in short, it looks like this :

```
const util = require("util");
const fs = require("fs");

util.promisify(fs.readFile)("foo.txt").then(data => {
  // Do something with data.
});
```

Or with `async/await`:

```
async function readFileAsPromise() {
  return await util.promisify(fs.readFile)("foo.txt");
}

readFileAsPromise().then(data => {
  // Do something with data.
});
```